# bash - increment variables that contain letters

Tags: bash

I have a set of valid characters [0-9a-z_] and a variable that is assigned one of these characters.  What I want to do is to be able to increment that variable to the next in the set.

If need be I can handle the "special" cases where it would increment from '9' to 'a' and 'z' to '_', but I can't figure out how to increment letters.

```
#!/bin/bash
y=b
echo $y  # this shows 'b'
y=$((y+1))
echo $y  # this shows '1', but I want it to be 'c'
```

Comment: are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13128083/297323

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
y=b
echo "$y"  # this shows 'b'
y=$(echo "$y" | tr "0-9a-z" "1-9a-z_")
echo "$y"  # this shows 'c'
```

Note that this does not handle the case where $y = "_" (not sure what you want then, and in any case it'll probably require separate handling), and if $y is more than one character long it'll "increment" all of them (i.e. "10" -> "21", "09g" -> "1ah", etc).

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I can handle the special cases where $y is more then one character long or when it equals "_".  This is a much nicer solution then the ugly array I used.  Thanks!

Comment: `y=b; y=$(tr "0-9a0-z" "1-9a-z_" <<< $y); echo $y;`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can be a solution:

```
a=({0..9} {a..z} _)
echo ${a[*]}
yc=11
echo ${a[yc]}
((++yc))
echo ${a[yc]}
echo ${a[++yc]}

#Alternative 
declare -A h
# Fill the has point to the next character
for((i=0;((i+1))<${#a[*]};++i)) { h[${a[i]}]=${a[i+1]};}
y=b
echo $y, ${h[$y]}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z _
b
c
d
b, c
```

Comment: This works, and is actually pretty close to what I built on my own, but it's not the most elegant solution.  There's gotta be a better way...

Comment: Actually this is uses exactly the same in idea what You accepted, but this uses less resources. At least two forks less and no exec to other external programs.

Answer (score 3):

You can start with this:

```
 echo 0x$(( $(printf "%x" "'b'") + 1)) | xxd -r
```

Answer (score 2):

**for those who would like to print incremented letter by execution of a function**:

```
ALPHA=( {A..Z} ) 
alpha_increment () { echo ${ALPHA[${i:-0}]}; ((i++)) ;}
```

---

```
alpha_increment
A
alpha_increment
B
alpha_increment
C
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this for a project, it uses the chr and ord fucntions(also found here somewhere) and some pure bash(only external called in the function is tr), if you are doing more than 100 characters I would use something else, but for short strings in my testing its actually slightly faster than python. 
Also this script lower cases any input, you will have to modify it for upper case. 
after putting these functions in your script(or cut and paste into a shell) you can just do

inc_string abz9z9

and get back.

aca0a0

```
chr() {
  [ "$1" -lt 256 ] || return 1
  printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$1")"
}

ord() {
  LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$1"
}

inc_string () 
{
string="$1";
lcstring=$(echo $string | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]');


for ((position=$((${#lcstring}-1));position>=0;position--));do  

  if [ "${lcstring:position:1}" = 'z' ]; then
    if [ "$position" -eq "$((${#lcstring}-1))" ]; then
       newstring="${lcstring:0:$(($position))}a";
       lcstring="$newstring";
    elif [ "$position" -eq "0" ]; then 
       newstring="a${lcstring:$((position+1))}";
       echo $newstring;
       break;
    else
       newstring="${lcstring:0:$(($position))}a${lcstring:$((position+1))}";
       lcstring="$newstring";
    fi
  elif [ "${lcstring:position:1}" = '9' ]; then
    if [ "$position" -eq "$((${#lcstring}-1))" ]; then
       newstring="${lcstring:0:$(($position))}0";
       lcstring="$newstring";
    elif [ "$position" -eq "0" ]; then  
       newstring="0${lcstring:$((position+1))}";
       echo $newstring;
       break;
    else
       newstring="${lcstring:0:$(($position))}0${lcstring:$((position+1))}";
       lcstring="$newstring";
    fi  
  else
    if [ "$position" -eq "$((${#lcstring}-1))" ]; then
       newstring="${lcstring:0:$(($position))}$(chr $(($(ord ${lcstring:position})+1)))";
       echo $newstring;
       break;
    elif [ "$position" -eq "0" ]; then
       newstring="$(chr $(($(ord ${lcstring:position})+1)))${lcstring:$((position+1))}";
       echo $newstring;
       break;
    else
       newstring="${lcstring:0:$(($position))}$(chr $(($(ord ${lcstring:position})+1)))${lcstring:$(($position+1))}";
       echo $newstring;
       break;               
    fi
  fi
done

}
```