# Update last character of string using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am new to shell script and  I want to update the last character of the string `/dev/sda` to next alphabet letter and loop through the count provided then write it into a file using shell script. could someone help me on this?

For Example: If Count is 10, so I want to loop 10 times to update the string and write in a file in next line with the updated string.

Sample File: myfile.txt

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd .... and so on
```

Comment: how would you handle z? or number?

Comment: may be with regex? @Popeye

Comment: Rather than editing the string, think about creating the string from a constant prefix `/dev/sd` and adding the appropriate letter.  At first sight, the `seq` command might do the job, but it only prints using floating point formats and only prints numbers (I have a variant `range` command that allowed me to use `range -f '%c' 97 103` to generate letters `a` through `g` — but `range` only deals with integers, not floating-point numbers).  It might be simplest just to list `for letter in a b c … z; do …; done`, breaking the loop when your count limit is reached.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823629/bash-increment-variables-that-contain-letters) might help (though it's far from the whole solution).

Comment: `echo /dev/sd{a..j}`?

Comment: @I0b0, yes it worked. but I need to loop the characters based on the count.. here we have hardcoded {a..j}

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it is not helping though.. since we are changing only the last character

Comment: `n=1; for i in {a..z}; do printf '%d %s\n' "$((n++))" "/dev/sd$i"; done` and viola! Create an assoicative array out of it, increment it, is up to you.

Comment: thanks @Jetchisel, its working.. but I want to print only the specific number which I am giving it as input. Ex. If I give my count as 5, the condition should loop through only 5 times and it should break and print.. but here we are printing from a to z. Do you have any idea on improving this based on the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all the possibilities, select only those you want.

```
printf '%s\n' /dev/sd{a..z} | head -n"$count"
```